# Google Form Search and Pull Spreadsheet Data

Tags: search, google-sheets, google-forms

Hi I have google spreadsheet that contains customers' ID and their shipping status. I want to create google form where customers are able to input each of their own ID, with the return that the google form shows their shipping status.

I tried to look for solutions in internet but there was no luck. I am not really good in programming, i hope there is answer to this problem without having me to do some hard programming.

The sample case can be seen in here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14vSAeZxEJTzbNLLYEiref6qt-CMqiVi8alheLcIBugM/edit?usp=sharing

Google form should show something a little bit like is shown in cell D1:E3.
Where customers can fill the form with their own customer id, and the google form shows the status.

Answer (score 2):

### Consideration

There is no way to respond back in a Google Form directly. You can't show custom validation messages after From submission either.

### Proposed solution

What about using email addresses additionally to the customerID to retrieve the shipping status? In this way you can easily build a notification system that will send an email if a matching customer ID is found in your spreadsheet.

To build such system you will have to build a Form with a Trigger.

It is required a bit of programming but I will try to cover the most important parts the best I can:

### Adapt your Database structure

Add the customers email addresses in the column C in order to be able to retrieve it using the same customer ID.

```
|  A |   B    |   C   |
|----+--------+-------|
| ID | STATUS | EMAIL |
```

### Build the Form Trigger

In the Form you are using click on the 3 dots from the top menu and select `Script Editor`. Here you will write the code that will power your notification system.

```js
function installTrigger() {
 // This function instructs the program to trigger the checkID function whenever a form response is submitted
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkID')
   .forForm(FormApp.getActiveForm())
   .onFormSubmit()
   .create();
}

function checkID(e) {
  // This function will parse the response to use the customer ID to retrieve email address and shipping status from the Spreadsheet Database
  var responses = e.response.getItemResponses(); // Gets the form responses
  var id = responses[0].getResponse(); // Assuming the first answer (index 0) is the customer ID)

  var found = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheet_id')
     .getRange('Sheet1!A1:C8') // The spreadsheet cells range in A1 Notation
     .getValues() // Retrieve their values in rows
     .filter((row) => row[0] == id); // Filter the rows for the provided customer ID

  if (found) {
    var status = found[0][1]; //Column B
    var email = found[0][2]; //Column C
    var subject = "Shipping Status";
    var message =
        `Hello!
          
         The status of the order number ${id} is: ${status}.`
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
  }
}
```

### Install the trigger

From the Script Editor top menu run the `installTrigger()` function: `Run>Run function>installTrigger`.

### You are done

Following these steps you have successfully set up the notification system. Now you can start sharing the Form link and accept responses.

### References

[Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

[Mail App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)

Comment: Wow okay I will surely give it a try as soon as possible!! Thankyou!! 

But i want to ask something out of curiosity, i don't find any "spreadsheet URL" variable. In case I want to change my database source into other spreadsheet, how can I edit it??

Comment: `var found = SpreadsheetApp.openById('11af2UYR5D5L2NQLhY58RumQAy2c6Q0iTPp_uHjGY4EE')` This is the line where i open the database spredsheet. You don't need the entire URL just the alpha-numeric ID: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/THIS-IS-THE-ID/edit`

Comment: You have it here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14vSAeZxEJTzbNLLYEiref6qt-CMqiVi8alheLcIBugM/edit?usp=sharing. This is the ID: 14vSAeZxEJTzbNLLYEiref6qt-CMqiVi8alheLcIBugM